# Improve pattern matching in R using grep

Tags: regex, r

Please help me to write a regex pattern in R

```
string1<-"kk<-"ccjar_neutral v_neutral vaux_neutral nnp_neutral prn_neutral v_neutral inj_neutral"
pattern="\\bv+\\_+[a-z]+\\s+[a-z]+\\_+[a-z]{1,10}\\b"
grep(pattern,string1)
```

The above pattern is not getting the next word only if it is "vaux". It is matching all the next words. please help me to write a pattern that matches only if v_neutral follows vaux_neutral
Also please explain the purpose of {} while writing a pattern.

Comment: Can you please show more examples and expected output?

Comment: What is your desired output? `[a-z]{1,10}` means 1 to 10 consecutive letters

Comment: The underscore doesn't need to be escaped. Is it possible that you explain clearly your requirements? (use the edit link without moderation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make use of a lookahead `?=`.

`v_neutral(?=\\s+vaux_neutral)`

`?=\\s+vaux_neutral`: looks ahead to see if there is one or more spaces followed by `vaux_neutral`

`v_neutral`: matches v_neutral if the look ahead condition is satisfied

see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lX5lX7/10)

Comment: Since the question is very unclear, I'm not sure that the OP is looking for something before or after "vaux_?????" and how this something looks like.

Comment: I want to write a pattern that will match "v_neutral vaux neutral" string from string1.

Comment: Look ahead operator is working fine in demo. But i am trying to run the code in R studio. it is throwing me an error. pat<-"v+\\_+[a-z]+\\s(?=+vaux+\\_+[a-z])"
r<-grep(pat,kk). Error is: Invalid regexp

Comment: don't escape the underscore `_`. leave it the way it is. Try this it should work for you `v_[a-z]+\\s(?=vaux_[a-z]+)`. Give me feedback if it works

Comment: It is still throwing an error. Error is : invalid regular expression 'v_[a-z]+\s(?=vaux_[a-z]+)', reason 'Invalid regexp'

Comment: Thank you james. By adding perl=TRUE solved the issue :)

Comment: thanks also for understanding. Accepting my answer would be really grateful